# Cannot mount and play copy-protected dvd Ubuntu 22.04 (libdvdcss is installed!)

Tags: mount, encryption, vlc, dvd, drm

Greetings to everybody.

I have a trouble in reading DRM-protected DVDs on my computer (Ubuntu 22.04). Those DVDs I own personally and I just want to watch them. System tries to read the DVD 3 times and fails. I can play audio CDs, DVDs with data (like DVDs with iso files recorded) I can even play movie DVDs without DRM protection. However there is no way to read licensed movie DVDs (encrypted?).
Before asking this question I've searched all this forum for answer.

NOTE: libdvdcss2 is installed!

I've tried:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras   
sudo apt install libavcodec-extra    
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg    
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

I've enabled multiverse package, installed Gstreamer plugins for basic, good, bad, ugly sets (funny names for sets)
Also I've tested my DVD drive with:

```
dd if=/dev/sr0 of=/dev/null bs=1M count=500 status=progress
```

to check if its working properly. Operation completed in 98,7921 sec with 5,3 MB/s speed, so DVD drive do work properly.

Also I've set regionset as was suggested here:

Here is VLC terminal output:

```
kobazauros@G550:/usr/share/doc/libdvdread8$ cvlc dvd:///dev/sr0
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
[000055aefdc1a410] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[00007f85e8001130] dvdnav demux error: Could not open /dev/sr0 with libdvdcss.
[00007f85e8001130] dvdnav demux error: Can't open /dev/sr0 for reading
[00007f85e8001130] dvdnav demux error: vm: failed to open/read the DVD
[00007f85e8001130] dvdread demux error: Could not open /dev/sr0 with libdvdcss.
[00007f85e8001130] dvdread demux error: Can't open /dev/sr0 for reading
```

After loading movie DVD dmesg -tl err shows no errors. However if I try to load data DVD and then try to load movie DVD dmesg -tl err shows:

```
UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_inode: (ino 1320830) failed !bh
UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_inode: (ino 1320829) failed !bh
UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_inode: (ino 1320828) failed !bh
UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_inode: (ino 1320827) failed !bh
```

By the way logs are filled with messages like:

```
Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 2179, async page read
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 8712 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
```

I'd appreciate any constructive help to solve this issue.

Comment: good question! And welcome to Ask Ubuntu! :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as stated in [OP's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1450863/618353), this was a hardware problem.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't believe it myself if someone told me. The problem was in hardware. I installed DVD drive from my ancient Toshiba Satellite L300 into my Lenovo Thinkpad laptop and all the licensed DVDs Lenovo refused to accept has been accepted.

The problem was specific to Lenovo Slimtype DVD and was resolved switching to another compatible device.

Thank you for your attention and your help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps installing libdvdcss2 will help.
This can be done trough  APT:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

Comment: maybe add how? would help. +1 too :) wishes from sweden

Comment: sudo apt install libdvdcss2

Comment: good+1  but I mean to the answer :I

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. CSS (the Content Scramble System) attempts to restrict the software that can play a DVD. By installing the libdvdcss2 package you can play encrypted DVDs. At least that's the theory... I always install it out of habit, but to be honest, it's been quite a while since I've played a DVD or a CD!

Comment: no worries; ^_^ thanks for replying too; And yes; it was 
awhile I did too, it's mostly files right now, anyway !  Regards from Sweden 8)

Comment: Greetings to all participators and special greetings to those from Sweden. 
I have a person that claims to be my friend there:)). 

Maybe I should explain more clearly. I've already installed libdvd-pkg. That means that libdvdcss-dev, libdvdcss2, libdvdnav4, libdvdread8 are already installed

Comment: Earlier as far as I could remember I've installed w32/w64 codecs - but now they are obsolete.
Any real help with diagnosing a problem would be appreciated. Thank you.